# Expanding the rows on click row of the table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a table A . On clicking any row of this table,I need to display data of other table B(having relational keys s_id).

Eg:
Table A:
id Name Age
1  abc  12
2  xyz  13

Table B:
id gender add
1  F       aghg
2  M       qwer

I want my output as: Table A should be printed as it is, and on click table A rows, Eg clicking on 1st row of table A should give 1st row of Table B, Clikin on 2nd row of A should give 2nd row of B and so on. Is it possible? Plz plz plz help me

The code I have is:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();


            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
            //$("#report").jExpand();
        });
    </script>        

<body>
    <table border="1"id="report">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>uda</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>lore</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
        blah blah
         <br />
        :(
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ish</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>ore</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <table width="335" s >
  <tr>
    <td>uda</td>
    <td>aixa</td>
    <td>diidi</td>
  </tr>

</table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This code prints the data that is typed in the form of  and .Also problem here is when I try to print the rows using mysql query it doesnt work.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM A");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<td><?php echo $row["source_id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["escl_status"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["escl_notice"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
    ?>
```

Please please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<tr>` in while loop like,

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM A");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr> <!-- add this tr -->
    <td><?php echo $row["source_id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["escl_status"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["escl_notice"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Also change `.odd` to `:odd` in your jquery selector,

```
$("#report tr:odd").click(function(){ // :odd not .odd
   $(this).next("tr").toggle();
   $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

Comment: Thank u, its working. I have edited my question plz have a look at it... plz

Comment: If it worked then tick it as correct answer and no need to edit it.